# Discord.py Embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I'm making a discord bot and I made a embed but it's not working I tried to make a new bot with few commands like ping and test but the bot is not replying

```
async def help(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.type != discord.ChannelType.private:
        if ctx.channel.id == 973394572627562506:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Help", description=".", color=0x71368A)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
            embed.add_field(name="tt", value="tt", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="ats", value="fw`", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="wf", value="awf", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="he", value="wf", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="ja", value="ge `(channel)`", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Twitch Hosts", value="gw", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Twitch Reports", value="!treport `(channel)`", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Twitch", value="gww `(channel)`", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Twitch ", value="wgw", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Twitch ii", value="twtw`", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="Made by Flame 'Em -_-rormommemm-_-#4779")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Did you override the `on_message` event? Did you enable and configure your intents?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the `@bot.command()` decorator to the function? Checkout the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html). Other than that the code seems right. You can also use the [discord embed generator](https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/) to make sure it will look like what you want and the code matches

Comment: Yeah i did add @bot.command()